# Fastest way for Windows users to rebuild an SD card?

Tags: windows, cygwin, raspberry-pi, sd-card, partitioning

I've built an SD card firmware, for Raspberry Pi. 
This firmware is made of two partitions : 1x FAT32 and 1x EXT4. What I'm trying to do, is to let Windows users install it as fast as possible on their own SD cards.

The classic way is to deliver a full SD card image, and let people flash it (using SD Formatter, Wind32DiskImager, etc). In most cases, it takes a lot of time.

On Unices however, it is also possible to build the partitions (parted) on the SD card, then copy the files there, and this is only a matter of minutes, if not less.

And so, my question : are there tools to proceed this way on Windows ?

Comment: how do you plan to "copy the files there", minitool partition wizard is a tool that lets you create multiple partitions easily. But I still dont get the question what is it that you want to achieve easily for windows users....

Comment: Well, I need help on creating the partitions. Minitool is an option, indeed, but that's still manual. What I meant with "easily" was that you can script it, so the users don't have to care about the SD card mapping. I was initially planning to use cygwin, but it doesn't include the mkfs tools to do that. +1 for making me clarify that :)

Comment: You can create partitions using cygwin, there are mkfs tools in the sbin directory, most of them are for linux file system when you install the default cygwin tools, but you can look for mkfs for other file systems, i.e. fat32 and others, a simple method would be, what I normally do is format it with another file system and then if windows doesnt recognize it, format it using windows it will automatically format the partitions and wont touch the other partitions....